# JavaScript slice / substring returning undefined only when replacing HTML innerText

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have programmed a simple RGB slider which shows its result on a HTML canvas. Everything works except a `slice` / `substring`: for some reason, when setting it to a variable or changing the innerText of a `<span>` it returns `undefined`.

```js
      const $ = ele => document.querySelector(ele),
      numToHex = num => parseInt(num, 10).toString('16').padStart(2, '0'),
      c = $('#canvas').getContext('2d')
      
      var rsp = $('#rspan'),
      gsp = $('#gspan'),
      bsp = $('#bspan'),
      rvalue, gvalue, bvalue
      
      $('#rrange').oninput = () => {
        rvalue = `#${numToHex($('#rrange').value).toUpperCase()}0000`
        rsp.innerText = rvalue
        rsp.style.color = rvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      $('#grange').oninput = () => {
        gvalue = `#00${numToHex($('#grange').value).toUpperCase()}00`
        gsp.innerText = gvalue
        gsp.style.color = gvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      $('#brange').oninput = () => {
        bvalue = `#0000${numToHex($('#brange').value).toUpperCase()}`
        bsp.innerText = bvalue
        bsp.style.color = bvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      function updateCanvas(rval = rvalue, gval = gvalue, bval = bvalue) {
        console.log(rval.substring(0, 3)) // This works
        let arr = [rval.substring(0, 3), gval.substring(3, 5), bval.substring(-2)]
        c.fillStyle = arr.join('') // Throws error
        c.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 250)
      }
```

```css
      input {
        width: 300px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RGB Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    <div id="rdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="rrange" />
      <span id="rspan"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="gdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="grange" />
      <span id="gspan"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="bdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="brange" />
      <span id="bspan"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening? It also throws the same error with `slice`. And why does it work in the prior `console.log` statement?

Comment: The error isn’t on the commented line with `arr.join('')`, right? It’s on the line before. Your first `console.log()` only tries `rval`, but `arr` is created from `rval`, `gval`, *and* `bval`, which are all initially `undefined` before each slider has had an `input` event.

Comment: When I run the code snippet, it says that `gval` is undefined.  That's different from what your code comments say.  Does the snippet work the same as your original problem?

Answer (score 0):

You currently don't always define `rvalue`, `gvalue`, and `bvalue` - they start out `undefined`, and all 3 only become assigned to once every slider has been changed at least once. Before that point, the `updateCanvas`:

```
function updateCanvas(rval = rvalue, gval = gvalue, bval = bvalue) {
```

will have at least one undefined parameter, so trying to access `.substring` on those undefined parameters will throw.

Set the color values to default to the middle of the range, `#808080`:

```
rvalue = '#808080',
gvalue = '#808080',
bvalue = '#808080';
```

You also need to slice the substrings properly when constructing the array - take 2 characters from each of red, green, and blue, then put them together and prefix them with `#`:

```js
const $ = ele => document.querySelector(ele),
      numToHex = num => parseInt(num, 10).toString('16').padStart(2, '0'),
      c = $('#canvas').getContext('2d')
      
      var rsp = $('#rspan'),
        gsp = $('#gspan'),
        bsp = $('#bspan'),
        rvalue = '#800000',
        gvalue = '#808080',
        bvalue = '#808080';
      
      $('#rrange').oninput = () => {
        rvalue = `#${numToHex($('#rrange').value).toUpperCase()}0000`
        rsp.innerText = rvalue
        rsp.style.color = rvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      $('#grange').oninput = () => {
        gvalue = `#00${numToHex($('#grange').value).toUpperCase()}00`
        gsp.innerText = gvalue
        gsp.style.color = gvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      $('#brange').oninput = () => {
        bvalue = `#0000${numToHex($('#brange').value).toUpperCase()}`
        bsp.innerText = bvalue
        bsp.style.color = bvalue
        updateCanvas()
      }
      
      function updateCanvas(rval = rvalue, gval = gvalue, bval = bvalue) {
        let arr = [rval.substring(1, 3), gval.substring(3, 5), bval.substring(5, 7)]
        console.log(arr);
        c.fillStyle = '#' + arr.join('') // Throws error
        c.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 250)
      }
```

```css
input {
        width: 300px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RGB Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    <div id="rdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="rrange" />
      <span id="rspan"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="gdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="grange" />
      <span id="gspan"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="bdiv">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="brange" />
      <span id="bspan"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```